# asterisk 11.7 with app_mp4 for playing mp4 videos

Tags: vlc-media-player, codec, mp4, asterisk

I have successfully compiled and run app_mp4 for asterisk 11.7 and recording audio/video with MP4Save. I am using ulaw as audio codec and h263 (simple h263 not 1998 or 2000) video codec. Although I can play and see video frames with vlc can't hear any audio. The result of mp4info command gives following information:

1   audio   G.711 uLaw, 72.090 secs, 2 kbps, 8000 Hz
2   hint    Payload PCMU for track 1
3   video   H.263, 0.000 secs, 0 kbps, 176x144 @ 0.000000 fps
4   hint    Payload H263 for track 3

although video is playable by vlc above information look to have problem with video record. and when I play same file using MP4Play in asterisk it gives series of errors as

[Nov 26 13:04:31] DEBUG[32185][C-00000000]: ../src/app_mp4.c:424 mp4_rtp_read: MP4ReadRtpHint failed [4,2]

I also have following queries:

1- should i save files in 3gp. does that makes any difference ?

2- does sequence/order of video hint information mp4info gives also matters?

Regards
Jamil

Answer (score 0):

You need install any codecpack with g711 codec.

Comment: Please expand upon this.  It isn't much help as it stands.

Comment: Expand to what? You just need codecs.

Comment: @arheops is your proposed solution related to asterisks and app_mp4.